# fix (lock) size of std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, locking, size, constants

Is there a way of fixing the size of a vector and still changing the contents?

I have tried making a const vector `const std::vector<int> vec(10);` but that prevents me from changing the values.

`vec[3] = 3;` gives a compiler error: assignment of read-only location.

I have also tried with a const reference to a non-const vector

```
std::vector<int> vec(10);
const std::vector<int>& vecref(vec);
```

which gives the same compiler error.

I want to be able to fix the vector size either on declaration or after an initialisation stage. I could use an old fashioned array, but I want to be able to use the vector algorithms.

I'm using g++ if that makes any difference.

Comment: What "vector algorithms" do you want to use? Anything in `<algorithm>` that works with a std::vector of fixed size, will work with a plain array, because the algorithms deal in iterators rather than containers.

Comment: I'm using `find_if`, `for_each` and a few others. I didn't realise that I could use them with plain arrays.

Comment: If you find here is a good answer, you should accept one :)

Answer (score 6):

With C++0x, you can use std::array<>, which is like a good old array, with the added benefit of being an STL container, therefore allowing many std::algorithms.

Alternatively, you may want to try boost::array.

- [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/array.html)
- [std::array](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-array)

Note that there is also `std::tr1::array<>`.

---

edit:

> Actually, one of the cases that I hadn't gone into was to grow the vector while reading configuration files and then fix the size after that - DanS

Then, why not this (illustrational):

```
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> foo;

    /* ... crunch upon foo ... */

    // make a copy vector->vector:
    const std::vector<int> bar (foo); 

    // make a copy any->vector
    const std::vector<int> frob (foo.begin(), foo.end());
}
```

Alternatively, if you need reset() semantics, but want to forbid resize() et al, you could write a container adapter:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator = allocator<T> >
class resettable_array {
public:
    // container ...
    typedef typename std::vector<T,Allocator>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename std::vector<T,Allocator>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    ...

    iterator begin() { return vector_.begin() }
    const_iterator begin() const { return vector_.begin(); }
    ...

    void push_back (T const &v) { vector_.push_back (v); }
    ...

    // custom
    void reset () { ... }

private:
    std::vector<T,Allocator> vector_;
};
```

See also:

- [std::vector constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/)

Comment: Another benefit of C++11 is `std::begin` and `std::end`, that also works with good-old standard fixed size arrays, like `int[5]`, hence also enabling the use of `std::algorithm` and `std::numeric` amongst other stl goodness.

Answer (score 3):

Embed it in an object that provides only the operations that you want to allow.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [const vector of pointers](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/const.html#fqa-18.1), and change the objects they point to. Not saying this is the right answer, just that it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [boost.array,](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/array.html) it gives you a fixed size array with vector semantics (with the exception of anything that would change the size of the array).

Comment: "vector semantics" is misleading and wrong. push_back, pop_back, resize and more are not supported by boost.array.

Comment: @phresnel: yes, of course. Edited to reinforce the fixed size nature of arrays.

Comment: Well to be fair push_back couldn't be supported by *any* answer to the poster's question, as it by definition alters the size of the array.

Comment: Actually, one of the cases that I hadn't gone into was to grow the vector while reading configuration files and then fix the size after that.

Comment: @DanS: in that case, std::array might not be for you. See me update answer (in some seconds).