# Is there a more natural way to represent a matrix of T than a vector< vector< T>>?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, standards

Context:

I am trying to learn C++ (while reading some of the stackoverflow community recommended books) and I decided to try and make a cellular automata program with basic functionality just for the sake of learning (and because it's interesting to me).

Question:

Is there a more natural way to represent a matrix of Cell elements than using a vector< vector< Cell>>?
I am looking for potential alternatives in the standard libraries or in some other popular libraries. Commentary regarding the performance would be appreciated.

I didn't have trouble using the vector of vectors, nor trouble with the syntax, I would just like to know alternatives. And because since I'm inexperienced, every time I write some code I imagine that probably there are a lot more straightforward ways to do it that I would not find by myself.

This is my first question so if I did something against the guidelines for questions I would appreciate a lot that you pointed it out.

Useful related question for future reference: [Is a vector<vector<double>> a good way to make a make a matrix class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939693/is-a-vectorvectordouble-a-good-way-to-make-a-make-a-matrix-class?rq=1)

Comment: If performance is a real issue then you are likely to get slightly better persormance from a raw multidimensional array: `Cell (*cells)[100] = new Cell[100][100];`. The reason being that the compiler can access the cells using a simple calculation rather than double dereferencing.

Comment: Since you asked: Don't include "thanks in advance" or any form of "thank you" in your question.  This isn't a forum.  As for your question: consider a Matrix<T> class that provides `operator()(size_t, size_t)` -- it can manage its memory however it likes, in particular avoiding the double-indirection of nested `vector`.  There's also [`std::valarray`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector), but it's specialized.

Comment: The "useful related question" is comparing a `vector of vectors` with an `array of arrays`. Both these approaches are likely to be less efficient that a genuine multidimensional array for the reasons I already outlined. A multidimensional array requires only one dereference followed by a simple calculation. Arrays of arrays (or vectors) require two dereferences.

Comment: @Galik: A multidimensional array is exactly an array of arrays.  Did you mean to compare it with an array of pointers to arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Matrix<double, 13, 3>
```

From the Eigen3 library http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html
Eigen3 provides pretty much every operation you'll need for linear algebra, and is well tested and used by a wide base of users.

Answer (score 4):

There's generally two ways to represent a two-dimensional array.

1. An array of pointers to other arrays, which is the model `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` uses.
2. One tightly packed array containing one row after another in memory. Then element `i, j` can be found at `i + j * width`.

Built-in multidimensional arrays in C++ are a bit weird, as they share similar syntax to 1, but the type
`T[10][10]` with the compilers I know of implements a scheme like 2. I don't know from the top of my head if this is mandated by the standard.

Comment: Multidimensional arrays must be implemented like 2. They are arrays of arrays, and arrays must be contiguous.

Comment: Also multidimensional arrays could be managed using smart pointers: `std::unique_ptr<Cell[][100]> cells(new Cell[100][100]);`

Comment: I like #2 with a wrapper class for easy use.

Answer (score 3):

I would be tempted to do something like this. I don't know how much speed advantage it might have over a vector of vectors so I would do some testing to check that. I assume it will have some speed advantage though.

```
typedef int Cell;

int main()
{
    // manage the raw multidimensional array pointer in a smart pointer
    // so no need to worry about memory leaks
    std::unique_ptr<Cell[][100]> cell_uptr(new Cell[100][100]);

    // work from the raw pointer (maybe save a dereference?)
    Cell(*cells)[100] = cell_uptr.get();

    for(size_t x = 0; x < 100; ++x)
    {
        for(size_t y = 0; y < 100; ++y)
        {
            // the compiler should be able to access cells[x][y]
            // based on a simple calculation rather than a second dereference
            cells[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
    // no need to worry about cleaning up
}
```

**NOTE:** The disadvantage of this approach is that the ***size*** of the array is ***fixed*** at compile time.

Comment: I am always willing to learn, can the down-voter (or anyone else) explain the problem(s)?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one major drawback of this approach is that the number of columns is fixed at compile-time.

Comment: @Ben Ah yes, thanks, I'll mention that in the answer.

Comment: @Galik I down voted because of the host of problems that come along with using C arrays. They are a relic of the past and should almost never be used, according to Bjarne Stroupstrup: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86xWVb4XIyE 1:17:40 is one place and there are other places in the video he mentions his distaste of C arrays (I recommend watching the whole video, for an understanding of modern C++ style).

Comment: @SteveM Straustrup is talking about "buffer overflow" problems and using a vector to eliminate that. No one in their right mind would use a raw buffer when they can simply use a vector. That's not relevant to this situation. Or even this question which **specifically asks** for **alternatives** to using `std::vector`. There are currently **no** modern containers in the standard library that can do the job of a *multidimensional* array and in this situation there is no real disadvantage to using one (managed with a smart pointer).