# Using a fixed length vector in a struct - C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
//stack.h

#ifndef STACK_H_INCLUDED
#define STACK_H_INCLUDED
#include <vector>

struct CharStack {
    int sp;
    std::vector<char> data(87);
} S;
```

But I get some errors like:

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

Why does that happen? There seems to be no problem when I want to create a vector with dynamic length

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623387/fix-lock-size-of-stdvector

Comment: If you want it to be "fixed size", why use vector?

Comment: @Chad I'd say it's the most elegant way to get the data to the heap. In C++11, a `std::unique_ptr<std::array<char, 87>>` would also be an option.

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but you don't want to define a global variable (`S`) in a header - that will give multiple definitions if you include the header from more than one source file. If you really want a global variable, you'll need to add `extern` here to make it a pure declaration, then define it in one source file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To construct objects in a struct (or class) you need to write a constructor. Like this

```
struct CharStack {
    CharStack() : data(87) {}
    int sp;
    std::vector<char> data;
} S;
```

It's just how C++ syntax is.

Comment: +1. Just a note: C++11 does allow initialisers at member declaration.

Answer (score 6):

You can't initialise a member in its declaration like that. In C++11, you can initialise it using `=` or a brace initialiser, for example:

```
std::vector<char> data = std::vector<char>(87);
```

Note that `data{87};` would do the wrong thing here, since that will populate the vector with a single value, rather than initialising it with that size.

If you're stuck in the past, then all non-static members need to be initialised by a constructor:

```
struct CharStack {
    CharStack() : data(87) {}  // and maybe initialise sp too

    int sp;
    std::vector<char> data;
};
```

However, if you actually want it to have fixed size (as implied by the question title), it might make more sense to be a `std::array<char, 87>`, or even a plain old `char[87]`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the construction of the vector to the constructor of the class.

```
struct CharStack {
    int sp;
    std::vector<char> data;

    CharStack() : data(87) {}
};
```

or, if you really want a fixed-sized structure and C++11 is an option, use `std::array`:

```
struct CharStack {
    int sp;
    std::array<char,87> data;
};
```